# Connecting WAMP server with Android 1.3

Tags: java, android, apache, import

I created my WAMPserver and started a project in the wwww directory file. However, when it comes to Android studio, I am not being able to import the corresponding classes to makes the server run via my app.

> ```
> import android.os.AsyncTask;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
> import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
> import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
> import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
> import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
> import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
> import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
> import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
> import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
> import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
> import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
> ```

The error is "Cannot resolve symbol".

NOTE: The error can be solved if i change the buildToolsVersion in my build.grade file to "22.2.0". But it is not working in this case.

my buildToolVersion is "23.0.1"

This is the complete code: Mainly I am detecting devices with WiFi-Direct enabled.. but now i wish to insert the data in the database on the server (That i can't seem able to integrate)

```
    package com.example.georges.mobilenetworking.Wifi_P2P;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;


import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import com.example.georges.mobilenetworking.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Wifi_P2P extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String serverURL = "127.0.0.1/451database";
    WifiP2pManager mManager;
    WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    IntentFilter mIntentFilter;



    public List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List peers = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi__p2_p);

        mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        mReceiver = new Wifi_P2P_Receiver(mManager, mChannel, this);

        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);


        // scan for devices
        mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d("DRCT", "discovering peers success !!");
                displayPeers();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mReceiver = new Wifi_P2P_Receiver(mManager, mChannel, this);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_wifi__p2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    void displayPeers(){
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.p2p);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, l);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }


}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you please post the complete stack trace?

Comment: please see edited post

Comment: I'm guessing the org.apache libraries were removed in build version 23 and you have to use something else